# Check Read and unread Message

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to conditionally style user-to-user messages on my site based on the following:

If the user has not yet accessed the message, it remains bold ("unread").
If the user clicks the link and accesses it, it goes from bold to unbold ("read")

(reference: this is how many email inboxes work)

Question: How would I check if the user has clicked on the link to view their new message, or if they have not? As in, how would I store this information and indicate that it has been "read"?

Comment: Show some code what have you tried so far?

Comment: How are you storing your messages? If it's with a database, it's as simple as 'setting a flag upon displaying the message'.

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking:** Please clarify your specific problem or **add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.** As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What's used to store data?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a column to your messages' table (for example read) and set this column to 1 when the user has read his message?